# Is there any way you could crop a logo to desired size with css?

Tags: css

I have a logo which i think the designer left a white background at the bottom,so it takes up free white space for nothing.I want to cut it out the unwanted white space from that logo,could i do that with css?Thank you in advance

Comment: not a css solution, but you can always add transparency to the image and save it as a png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could set the image as a background image and simply make the element's dimensions smaller, effectively *cropping* the image.

```
div {
    background: url(path/to/image.png);
    width: 32px;
    height: 16px;  
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

However, you really ought to remove the space yourself (why send more bytes around for no reason?) and ask the designer to send better images.